# Cannot cast result from Sub-Select to numeric

Tags: sql, sybase, velocity, sqlanywhere

I am selecting a list of IDs as a sub-query in a condition but it says it cannot convert '123,456' to numeric. The problem occurs in the last line. DB is Sybase-SQL-Anywhere.

```
SELECT
 ISNULL(SUM(a.menge), 0) AS menge,
 ISNULL(SUM(a.wert), 0) AS wert
FROM admin.p_ws_ix_kontrakte_ernte_auswertung_jensek a
WHERE
 (a.KtrErnteJahr = ? OR ? IS NULL)
AND (
 (a.KtrDispoKennz >= ? OR ? IS NULL)
AND
 (a.KtrDispoKennz <= ? OR ? IS NULL)
)
AND a.artikelstammid IN ((SELECT LIST(artikelstammId) FROM admin.ws_ix_auswertung_cfg_spalten_artikel WHERE columnId = $column))
```

Comment: I don't know sybase syntax, but in common SQL I would use `IN(SELECT artikelstammId FROM...`, without `LIST()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `LIST()`:

```
# replace this:

AND a.artikelstammid IN ((SELECT LIST(artikelstammId) FROM admin.ws_ix_auswertung_cfg_spalten_artikel WHERE columnId = $column))

# with this:

AND a.artikelstammid IN (SELECT artikelstammId FROM admin.ws_ix_auswertung_cfg_spalten_artikel WHERE columnId = $column)
```

Another option would be an `exists/correlated subquery`:

```
# replace this:

AND a.artikelstammid IN ((SELECT LIST(artikelstammId) FROM admin.ws_ix_auswertung_cfg_spalten_artikel WHERE columnId = $column))

# with this:

AND exists (SELECT 1 FROM admin.ws_ix_auswertung_cfg_spalten_artikel b WHERE b.columnId = $column and b.artikelstammId = a.artikelstammid)
```